# an identity related to the pentagonal numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics

How can I prove the following?

$$1-x+x^2+x^5-x^7-x^{12}+x^{15}-x^{22}-x^{26}+x^{35}-x^{40}+\dots \\=  \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} [(1 - x^{8 i - 7}) (1 + x^{8 i - 6}) (1 + x^{8 i - 5}) (1 + 
    x^{8 i - 4}) (1 + x^{8 i - 3}) (1 + x^{8 i - 2}) (1 - 
    x^{8 i - 1}) (1 - x^{8 i})]$$

It doesn't seem to follow from the Triple Product formula and I haven't been able to come up with a combinatorial proof.

Comment: What is that left hand side? Is there a pattern to the signs? Or are you just claiming that the coefficients are all $\pm 1$ (or $0$)?

Comment: @ZachTeitler It is the series for the expansion of $\prod_i(1-x^i)$ but with different signs.

Comment: Coefficients of lhs seem to be [A206958](http://oeis.org/A206958) in OEIS. If so then according to that page, it is the expansion of$f(x^5,-x^7) -xf(-x,x^{11})$, where$$f(a,b)=1 +(a+b) +(ab)(a^2+b^2) +(ab)^3(a^3+b^3) +(ab)^6(a^4+b^4) + (ab)^{10}(a^5+b^5)+...$$is the Ramanujan theta function with the infinite product representation $(-a;ab)_\infty(-b;ab)_\infty(ab;ab)_\infty$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes, that identity follows from the Riemann addition relation of theta functions, see relation (5) in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuintupleProductIdentity.html

Answer (score 14):

This is an instance of [Watson's quintuple product identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintuple_product_identity) (also Macdonald identity for $BC_1$):
$$\prod_{n\geq 1}(1-s^n)(1-s^nt)(1-s^{n-1}t^{-1})(1-s^{2n-1}t^2)(1-s^{2n-1}t^{-2})=\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}s^{\frac{3n^2+n}{2}}(t^{3n}-t^{-3n-1}).$$
By plugging in $t=x^{-1}$ and $s=-x^{4}$ this becomes exactly your identity.

Somewhat amusingly, the quintuple product identity can be proven directly from the triple product identity. See [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-032-01/S0002-9939-1972-0289316-2/) article by Carlitz, or [this](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-56513-7_15) article of Foata and Han.